# How do I get the path of app in its launch script?

Tags: finder, script

I made an app by following these steps

1. Make folder `Foo.app`
2. Make Subfolder `Contents`
3. Put `Info.Plist` in `Contents` with

   ```
   ...
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>Foo</string>
   ...
   ```
4. Make `MacOS/Foo` as an executable shell script

`Foo` looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $0 > /Users/me/temp/foo1
pwd > /Users/me/temp/foo2
export > /Users/me/temp/foo3
```

Clicking on the app in the finder then checking the results. The results are, foo1 is empty, foo2 is just `/` and foo3 looks like

```
export Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FgQwJ5EVCp/Render"
export HOME="/Users/me"
export LOGNAME="me"
export OLDPWD
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PWD="/"
export SHELL="/bin/zsh"
export SHLVL="1"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4hbrl5p8fp/Listeners"
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/7h/wyw4jhd933z5jmqzsdx6r0sr0000gn/T/"
export USER="me"
export __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0x0:0x0"
```

No references to `/Applications/Foo.app` anywhere

Now do I get the path to my app in the launch script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo $DIR >  /Users/me/temp/outLog.txt
```

It'll give you path to the `MacOS` folder of you app.

Here's great [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) about this.